# Selenium has an IPv6 issue when using firefoxdriver

Tags: c#, selenium, ipv6

I am trying to use Selenium to drive some web tests in Firefox, however when I do this

```
FirefoxDriver _driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

I get this  exception

> An address incompatible with the requested protocol was used
>   [::1]:7055

This appears to be some sort of IPv6 vs IPv4 issue that selenium is not going to fix. however I need to work around it. Disabling IPv6 on my Ethernet makes no difference. what else can I try?

Cheers

Comment: What version of the bindings do you have? What version of Firefox do you have? Do you get the same issue with other drivers - such as the ChromeDriver?

Answer (score 2):

I'm making a few assumptions here, but this looks like an issue I had using Selenium on Windows when connecting to a URL on localhost. The issue may be due to localhost resolving as ::1 instead of 127.0.0.1 on Windows 2008.

If that is the case add the line 
`127.0.0.1       localhost`
into C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts